# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the following error:

```
        LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [System.Int32] get_st_past_enrollment_success()' 
method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

This is caused by the following linq

```
IEnumerable<subject> _subjects = (from subject in context.subjects
                           where 
                                subject.enrollments.Count() < subject.sj_max_enrollment
                                && subject.sj_availability == true
                                && !this.get_st_past_enrollment_success().Contains(subject.sj_subject_id)

                           select subject);
```

get_st_past_enrollment_success() returns a List:

```
public List<int> get_st_past_enrollment_success()
        {
            return this.enrollments.Where(e => e.em_enrolled == false && e.em_result >= 50).Select(e => e.em_subject_id).ToList();
        }
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query itself contains the method call - and Entity Framework doesn't know what to do with that. Try extracting the list fetch to before the query:

```
var enrollments = get_st_past_enrollment_success();

var _subjects = from subject in context.subjects
                where subject.enrollments.Count() < subject.sj_max_enrollment
                      && subject.sj_availability
                      && !enrollments.Contains(subject.sj_subject_id)
                select subject;
```

Also note that `get_st_past_enrollment_success` violates [.NET naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) - that won't affect whether the code works, but it'll look odd to other developers who are used to the normal conventions.

Comment: thanks that solved it. 

yeah i know it does that but sql naming conventions say you need to use underscores with the first two letters representing the table name. In order to solve that i would have to to getst_past_enrollment_success which is a bit weird. With java's jpa you can create synomyms, with c# efw that's not possible...

Comment: @bicycle: But you're not writing SQL - you're writing C#. So follow SQL naming conventions in your SQL, and C# naming conventions in your C#. (I would personally make your entity model use .NET conventions as well, for the property names. That doesn't mean that your SQL field names need to change.)

Comment: where is it posisble then to change the property names without them being overwritten every time you reload the model? In the edmx diagram?

Comment: In java jpa you define the java property names directly in the generated poco class. I don't know where to do that with the efw.

Comment: @bicycle: I don't know the details, but you should certainly be able to change them. I wouldn't pay too much attention to what you do in JPA though - EF is likely to be very different in many ways.